# htop reports 100% cpu steal time, top reports 0% after virsh restore

Tags: linux, kvm, libvirt, htop

After a virsh save + restore from file, `htop` reports ~100% cpu steal time (st), while `top` reports ~100% idle time.

May this be a bug in `htop`? Are there any fixes available, or is this simply some strange qemu/kvm behavior?

[image: htop]
[image: top]

*Debian 8, Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64, htop 1.0.3, top (procps-ng) 3.3.9, virsh 1.2.9*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ganeti/D2Yos3BShmc), this is caused by a bug in KVM and is fixed in KVM 2.1.3 and 2.2.

The latest Debian package (`kvm-qemu 1:2.1+dfsg-12+deb8u2`) does not seem to include that fix.